# Nifi API: Is it possible to delete one specific element in a flowfile queue?

Tags: apache-nifi, nifi-api

Looking through the nifi API docs : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html
it seems there is `drop-request` endpoint that gives you the possiibility to drop the entire queue. What if I want to drop a single flowfile? Is there a way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: everything that is possible to do through UI - possible to replicate through api.

Comment: @daggett So... since it's not possible to delete a single element from the queue, I guess I can't ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't drop a specific flowfile in a queue, however you can put that queue through some processor to separate that flowfile into a different queue and drop it there. Remember that queues can be moved to other processors if they are all stopped.